# To convert time stamp in lua

Tags: lua

The current date and time format we're getting from the device is (DD-MON-YY) **07-NOV-23** and (HH.MM) **16.30**.

SO we need to re-format as **"2023-11-07T16:30:00.000000Z** before pushing into the payload.

We tried below LUA
`local a=self.value['raindate'].value\nlocal b=self.value['raintime'].value\nvalue=string.format('%sT%s',a,b)`
and the result was **23-NOV-23T16:30**

we're trying to achieve the output as **2023-11-07T16:30:00.000000Z**

Requesting anyone help on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you need to match each date and time element, get the numeric value of the month,
set it all as a table and then convert it to a formatted string:

```
local a='07-NOV-23' --self.value['raindate'].value
local b='16.30' --self.value['raintime'].value

local dd, mm, yy = string.match(a,'(%d+)%-(%w+)%-(%d+)')
local hour, min = string.match(b,'(%d+)%.(%d+)')

local months = { ["jan"]=1, ["feb"]=2, ["mar"]=3, ["apr"]=4,  ["may"]=5,  ["jun"]=6, 
                 ["jul"]=7, ["aug"]=8, ["sep"]=9, ["oct"]=10, ["nov"]=11, ["dec"]=12 }
local month = months[string.lower(mm)]

-- 1) with os library: 
local t = {year='20'..yy, month=month, day=dd,hour =hour , min=min, sec=0 }
print (os.date ("%Y-%m-%dT%X.000000Z",os.time(t)) )
-- 2) or simply:
print( string.format('20%d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:00.000000Z', yy,month, dd, hour, min ) )

-- 2023-11-07T16:30:00.000000Z
```

Comment: Thanks Mike this helps a lot, but in our edge we can't use function or os library, so we're still stuck :(

Comment: I corrected the answer, with an example without os library

Comment: Hi Mike, I can see the 2nd option working. Thanks for the help. Can we also add or minus the timezone here. For ex. the current time mention in the result is 16.30 can we make the code for the particular timezone like adding or subtracting the hours by 5 hours 30 mins

Comment: I didn't understand the question, just change the 'hour' and 'min' values

Comment: I'll explain.. So, we have a sensor device which sends the current date and time in IST (+5.30) (we cannot change the time in that). For ex. when the device send time as 19.30 hours, by lua can we change it to 14.00 (i.e. +0.00)?

Comment: `hour = hour-5; min=min-30;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this way...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/lua
-- dtref.lua
local raindate, raintime, dtab, conv = arg[1] or [[19-JAN-38]], arg[2] or [[03.14]], {}, ""
-- DEBUG! - Disable os library
os = nil

dtab["day"] = tonumber(raindate:sub(1, 2))
dtab["month"] = tonumber((raindate:gsub("%u+", {["JAN"] = "01",
["FEB"] = "02",
["MAR"] = "03",
["APR"] = "04",
["MAY"] = "05",
["JUN"] = "06",
["JUL"] = "07",
["AUG"] = "08",
["SEP"] = "09",
["OCT"] = "10",
["NOV"] = "11",
["DEC"] = "12"})):sub(4, 5))
dtab["year"] = tonumber(("20%s"):format(raindate:sub(8,9)))
dtab["hour"] = tonumber(raintime:sub(1, 2))
dtab["min"] = tonumber(raintime:sub(4, 5))
dtab["sec"] = 0                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                              
-- If os Library is present use it else use string.format()                                                                                                                                   
if os ~= nil then                                                                                                                                                                             
  print("os.date()")
  conv = os.date("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00.000000Z", os.time(dtab))                                                                                                                                  
else                                                                                                                                                                                          
  print("string.format()")
  conv = ("%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:00.000000Z"):format(dtab.year, dtab.month, dtab.day, dtab.hour, dtab.min)                                                                                           
end                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                              
if #arg == 0 then                                                                                                                                                                             
  print(conv)                                                                                                                                                                                 
elseif #arg == 2 then                                                                                                                                                                         
  print(conv)                                                                                                                                                                                 
end                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                              
return(conv)
```

Example of use when os Library is disabled...

```
€ chmod +x dtref.lua
€ ./dtref.lua
string.format()
2038-1-19T3:14:00.000000Z
€ ./dtref.lua 24-DEC-99 23.59
string.format()
2099-12-24T23:59:00.000000Z
```

Known *nix Bug (Y2K38) when using os Library: Cant get Date above 19. Jan 2038 04:14 here (CET)
(At UTC 03:14:07)

```
€ ./dtref.lua 19-JAN-38 04.14
os.date()
2038-01-19T04:14:00.000000Z
€ ./dtref.lua 19-JAN-38 04.15
os.date()
/usr/local/bin/lua: ./dtref.lua:28: time result cannot be represented in this installation
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'os.time'
    ./dtref.lua:28: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

( I change hardcoded values as a warning and border :-) )